# What do you call a wide, solid bracelet?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, nouns

What is this type of bracelet called? Does it have any specific word for it or just a bracelet?

In the manga, which picture 1 below is from, it is called shackles. But these sorts of ornaments are worn in many cultures and I’m not sure whether shackles is a proper word either.

[image]

[image]

[Image 1 Source: “The Live” manga]
[Image 2 Source: https://www.artstation.com/artwork/yk9W8Q]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JewelryShoppingGuide.com](https://www.jewelryshoppingguide.com/different-types-of-bracelets/#Cuff_Bracelet) suggests that it might be called a **cuff bracelet**.

Note that "cuff" as in [**handcuffs**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handcuff#English) carries a meaning in English that is *similar* to [**shackle**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shackle#English) but less so, or at least that is how I see the terms:

- Handcuffs are used on people who have been arrested and are being transported to a police station, or on prisoners who are temporarily outside of their jail cell (e.g. in a courtroom). They bind the prisoner's wrists together.
- Shackles are a more permanent restraint, used for long-term punishment. The shackle fits around the prisoner's wrist and is attached to a length of chain which is bolted into a wall, or perhaps it fits around the ankle and is attached to a heavy object (the proverbial ["ball and chain"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ball+and+chain)). I'm no expert but it seems like the use of shackles would likely be deemed "cruel and unusual" today. When I hear the word "shackle" I think of a medieval dungeon, not a modern prison.

---

It might be the case that in certain cultures (like Japanese/manga fandoms) such pieces of jewelry are called **shackles**. But unless you know that for sure, it would be safer to call them **cuff bracelets**.

Comment: Well, “cuff bracelet” isn’t a satisfactory word. But what can you do if that’s the only word for that thing, right? Thanks! for answering.